# template parameter deduction for container

Tags: c++, c++11

My problem is, that I don't know a way to force the compiler to deduce template parameters without the use a dummy parameter. Here's a nonworking example:

```
template<int I, class C, class T, std::size_t N>
inline typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<C, std::array<T, N> >::value,
  std::array<T, N> >::type
create_container()
{
  std::array<T, N> array;
  // I is used somewhere
  return array;
}
```

Here's a working example:

```
template<int I, typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> create_container(std::array<T, N> const&) // dummy parameter helps deduction
{
  std::array<T, N> array;
  // I is used somewhere
  return array;
}
```

The template parameter `C` specifies what container to instantiate in the first example, but in the second the function is selected based on the dummy parameter. Is SFINAE or some other magic possible? Partial template specialization comes to mind, but it is not possible with function templates.

`create_container` is called like this:

```
template <std::size_t O, typename R, typename ...A, std::size_t ...I>
inline R forward(R (*f)(A...), indices<I...>)
{
  return (*f)(create_container<I + O, A>()...);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling your `create_container()` when you don't pass the dummy argument?

Comment: Are you sure your "working example" works?  `typename N` seems quite wrong, and it would help if the arguments were names instead of single letters.

Comment: Also, you have an extra angular bracket in the non-working example after `>::type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just missing a type traits to detect whether C is a `std::array<T,N>`? If so:

```
template< typename >
struct is_std_array : std::false_type {};

template< typename T, std::size_t N >
struct is_std_array< std::array< T, N > > : std::true_type {};
```

and

```
template<int I, typename C>
typename std::enable_if< is_std_array< C >::value, C >::type create_container()
{
   C container;

   // to access T and N from std::array<T,N>, use this:
   typedef typename C::value_type T;
   constexpr std::size_t N = container.size();

   // I is used somewhere
   return container;
}
```

Comment: I need to know `T` and `N` in the body of the function.

Comment: Would it not be possible to change `is_std_array` to store T and N somewhere, say a `typedef` and `const static` member?

Comment: Yes, but why? Single responsibility principle: Let `is_std_array` just do one thing and the rest is already available through other means.